# How edit the Context Menu pop up in UITextView when interacting with NSTextAttachment

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

I am trying implement a `UITextView` with image attachments. When you long press on a `NSTextAttachment` in the `UITextView` you get a menu containing some actions (e.g. copy image, save to camera roll). What I am trying do is adding/editing options in this menu like **Apple**'s notes app does. I have seen other notes apps doing the same thing (e.g. bear app), but I can't seem to find a way to implement or access this. Can you tell me how to implement this?

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        setUpTextView()
        loadAttributedText()
    }
    
    func setUpTextView() {
        textView = UITextView()
        
        textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        textView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        textView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        textView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        
        view.addSubview(textView)
        
        //Setup Constarints
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    func loadAttributedText() {
        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is a sunflower\n")
        
        let image = UIImage(named: "flower")!
        let compressedImage = image.compressImage(to: CGSize(width: 300, height: 400))
        
        let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment(image: compressedImage)
        let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)
        
        attributedText.append(attachmentString)
        attributedText.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .semibold), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.length))
        
        textView.textStorage.setAttributedString(attributedText)
        
    }
}

extension UIImage {
    func compressImage(to maxSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        
        let availableRect = AVFoundation.AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: self.size, insideRect: .init(origin: .zero, size: maxSize))
        let targetSize = availableRect.size
        
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: targetSize, format: format)
        
        let resized = renderer.image { (context) in
            self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize))
        }
        
        return resized
    }
}
```

I have used an extension for `UIImage` to compress an image to fit the textView's width.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "flower")!
```

Here "flower" is a jpeg image in my project's asset. So you will have to add an image in your project's assets and use it here in order to test this.

I have also attached some images to explain the problem.

**This is the default behaviour I get:**

[image]

**This is the apple note's app behaviour which I want:**

[image]

Comment: So you want to add a delete button and a "Small Images" button? What would "Small Images" do?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19868737/5133585) answer your question?

Comment: this post uses a UIActionSheet but I want a context menu.